# "floppy: error 10 while reading block 0" after distribution upgrade

Tags: boot

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, my startup takes over 3 minutes attempting something like floppy disk reads (with no floppy disk existing).

This is the excerpt `/var/log/boot.log` that I roughly see during startup, although during startup there seems to be some more output (including some note about giving up waiting) that I do not find in the logs after the boot completes:

```
[    4.034457] ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.370680] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    4.706681] ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    5.204035] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    5.227738] ata5.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HDS721010CLA332, JP4OA3MA, max UDMA/133
[    5.249953] ata5.00: 1953525168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    5.273709] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    5.296052] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HDS72101 A3MA PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    5.318606] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    5.318752] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[    5.318812] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    5.318813] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    5.318890] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    5.366205]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4
[    5.366658] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    5.936034] ata6: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    5.959911] ata6.00: ATAPI: TSSTcorp DVDWBD SH-B123L, SB03, max UDMA/100
[    5.985249] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    6.010890] scsi 5:0:0:0: CD-ROM            TSSTcorp DVDWBD SH-B123L  SB03 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    6.098266] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    6.121604] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    6.144998] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    6.145208] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[   60.388280] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[   60.412397] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[   83.427787] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[   83.452049] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  106.380206] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  106.404593] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  106.429281] random: crng init done
[  129.368293] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  129.392645] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  153.408135] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  153.432814] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  176.423440] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  176.448027] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  199.631450] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  199.655318] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  222.659803] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  222.683064] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  245.843419] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  245.865876] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  268.856302] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  268.878046] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  292.004186] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  292.025434] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  315.024279] print_req_error: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[  315.045328] floppy: error 10 while reading block 0
[  315.553949] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

What causes this output and how can I eliminate the problem?

Comment: same problem. maybe it should be reported on the bug report

Comment: I arrived here after just updating to 18.04 - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/384579 suggests you may genuinely have an active floppy controller and the failures are genuine attempts to access the non-existent floppy.  Disabling floppy controller in bios should resolve.

Comment: I got this problem when running Ubuntu 20.04 in Hyper-V and the suggestion in comment #7 on the [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/384579/comments/7) given by Greg above, solved the problem for me (machine now boots faster without the floppy error messages).